# JForm::addFormPath to load Template path

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin

I Have a plugin and I have the Following code working fine:

```
if ($this->params->get('thepath') == 'plugins'){

       JForm::addFormPath(JPATH_PLUGINS.'/system/add_xml_fields/');

      }
```

I need to load the actual default template path and your overrides, like this:

```
if ($this->params->get('thepath') == 'template_override'){
        foreach ($themodules as $key=>$themodule){
            if ($data->module==$themodule) {
                JForm::addFormPath($tpath.'html'.$themodule.'/');
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I make this to work. Actually do not load anything :(

Answer (score 1):

Solved, using a database query like this bellow:

```
if ($this->params->get('thepath') == 'template_override'){
foreach ($themodules as $key=>$themodule){
    if ($data->module==$themodule) {
        $db = JFactory::getDBO();
        $query = "SELECT template FROM #__template_styles WHERE client_id = 0 AND home = 1";
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $defaultemplate = $db->loadResult();
        JForm::addFormPath( JPATH_SITE.'/templates/'.$defaultemplate.'/html/'.$themodule.'/');
    }
}
```